# Atom script configure script run python 2.7

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have downloaded Anaconda on my computer however Anaconda is installed for all users on my mac therefore when I try and access python2.7 by typing in the path: /anaconda3/envs/py27/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Even if I open from terminal the path above is not in the current directory since:

machintoshHD/anaconda3/....
machintoshHD/Users/adam/desktop....

how can i redirect the configure script feature in the atom package script so that i can run python 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I can change Atom python is to run it from a directory that has a different default python version. if I type python from a terminal window, whichever version of python that opens is the version Atom uses. I use virtual environments so I can run python 2.7.13 or python 3.6. If I want Atom to run python 3, I activate my python 3 environment and then run atom.
There may be a way to do this from within Atom but I haven't found it yet.